# How and why does $\ln ^{\alpha}(1+ x^2)\to x^{2 \alpha}$ when $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

$\ln ^{\alpha}(1+ x^2)\to x^{2 \alpha}$ when $x\to 0$ this is something that I need currently and forgot to study when I should have, now I dont understand this..

Comment: First of all, that doesn't make sense. You can say that $\ln^\alpha(1+x^2)\sim x^{2\alpha}$ when $x$ near zero. But the limit is just $0$ (for $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the taylor expansion. For small x, higher powers are insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: for a fix $\alpha \neq 0$, $\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}\right)^{\alpha}\to 1$